# Serenity BDD ConfigurationException after updating IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, serenity-bdd

I try to run my BDD scripts via gradle getting the following error message after updating IntelliJ to 2016.2

```
No implementation for net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebdriverManager was bound.
  while locating net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebdriverManager
```

The code raising the error is this:

```
@Before
public void jeffCanBrowseTheWeb() {
    givenThat(jeff).can(BrowseTheWeb.with(theBrowser));
}
```

The binaries to the browser are linked like this:
test {

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\lib\\chromedriver.exe")

/* Pass all system properties: */
systemProperties System.getProperties()}
```

- The compile dependencies for selenium-java are pointing to the version '2.53.1'
- The gradle command: clean test aggregate

I cannot figure out what is wrong since I did nothing else but updating the IDE. Maybe someone has a hint?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: Edit: Putting the webdriver's binaries location in a config file as described in http://testerstories.com/2016/06/screenplay-pattern-with-java-part-1/ webdriver.driver=chrome
webdriver.chrome.driver = path_to_chromedriver did not help either

Comment: Solved the problem by removing the test entry in build.gradle and using  the serenity.properties instead: `webdriver.driver=chrome` and 
`webdriver.chrome.driver=F:\\path-to\\chromedriver.exe`

Comment: Please let me know your maven dependencies. I got stuck with same issue and I know root cause is conflict in maven dependencies. Can you share your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I was following the example in the article mentioned in your comment. In my case (without using an IDE) it seemed to be a out-of-date dependency (which was renamed).

Try changing the dependency 'net.serenity-bdd:browse-the-web' to 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver' in build.gradle.